# Brew shows elasticsearch server is running, but request to elasticsearch server keeps failing

Tags: bash, macos, elasticsearch

I am not sure if elasticsearch is installed in my Mac.
macOS: 10.14
elasticsearch: 5.6

This is what I tried:

1. **Bash Command:** `elasticsearch`

   **Result:** `-bash: elasticsearch: command not found`
2. **Bash Command:** `brew search elasticsearch`

   **Result:**
   `==> Formulae elasticsearch    elasticsearch@2.4   elasticsearch@5.6✔`
3. **Bash Command:**  `brew services start elasticsearch`

   **Result:**

   ```
   Service `elasticsearch@5.6` already started, use `brew services restart elasticsearch@5.6` to restart.
   ```
4. **Bash Command:** `brew services restart elasticsearch@5.6`

   **Result:**

   ```
   ==> Successfully ran `elasticsearch@5.6` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch@5.6)
   ```

But when I tried to curl http://localhost:9200/
I get *curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused*

My app server throws this error:
*Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)):*

Even when I reinstalled elasticsearch, I am running into this problem again.

**Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Check the log file

Comment: In logs I could find 'All shards failed', so I manually deleted all shards and reinstalled elasticsearch again, now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In logs I could find 'All shards failed' this error.

Running `brew info elasticsearch@5.6`
I got this:

```
Data:    /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_suryapandian/

Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_suryapandian.log

Plugins: /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch@5.6/libexec/plugins/

Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/

plugin script: /usr/local/opt/elasticsearch@5.6/libexec/bin/elasticsearch-plugin
```

After uninstalling elastic search using brew
`brew uninstall elasticsearch@5.6`

Manually I checked in all these locations if any of elasticsearch was still present and removed all of it.To make sure that all the old shards gets deleted.

Then I installed elasticsearch again. Now elasticsearch is running smoothly.

Comment: Over the years I have had to move through a lot of versions of ElasticSearch. This is always the issue. After you uninstall a version, comb through all of the locations identified above and just delete the ElasticSearch folders. Then when you reinstall everything will come through clean. As an easy test, once it is all installed, you can use `curl localhost:9200` to make sure the server is running and responding.